# rails join model for search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having trouble with this conceptually, so I hope I can find some guidance on how to approach this task.

The example is somewhat arbitrary but I hope it serves to show my aim here.

3 Models, joined

```
class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :models
end
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  has_many :editions
end
class Edition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model
end
```

I want to combine the data, in order to search any match

```
<% @editions.each do |edition| %>
  <% model = edition.model %>
  <% manufacturer = model.manufacturer %>
  <%= "#{manufacturer.name} #{model.name} #{edition.name}" %>
```

To complicate this.  I would like to treat this as 3 selections in order to keep track.

The way I forsee this is using fuzzy search for matching, and tokeninput or similar to display while seperating the matches.

Off the top of my head I believe eBay may do something similar as part of their quick listing sales page.

### Thoughts:

- Model.find(:all, :joins => [:editions, :manufacturer] ) will give me everything, but this wouldn't scale to a fourth model?
- Assuming I need to use these captures in a search form or otherwise, I need to both separate them inside the text field as well as in the controller.
- The alternative I suppose is to store this in a single table, either permanently or as a lookup table.  A single selection in this contains reference to gather all the information

[image: Search results from combined models]

And then something like

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :manufacturer
    has_one :model
    has_one :edition
end
```

Comment: Not sureI quitei understand what your attempting to accomplish here, can you explain further?

Comment: Also, based on what I think you are asking... Performance wise you may need to use a full text search engine like ElasticSearch with the "tire" gem

Comment: Added an image to show what I'm thinking (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, what about something like:

```
@editions = Edition.joins(model: :manufacturer)
  .where("models.name = :q OR manufacturers.name = :q OR editions.name = :q", q: params[:q])
```

Comment: Seems like a solid solution.  I think that I probably over-complicated the process a lot; I don't really get to sit down to this stuff until > midnight, so that's where I'm putting the blame.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, yes you can do this with joins instead of storing it in a single table.
To make it super simple I'd use the squeel gem by Ernie Miller
http://railscasts.com/episodes/354-squeel
It allows this kind of syntax:

```
Edition.joins{ model.manufacturer }.where{ (edition.name =~ "%#{params[:q]}%") || ( edition.model.name =~ "%#{params[:q]%}" || ( edition.model.manufacturer.name =~ "%#{prams[:q]}%" ) }
```

If the table gets big, this may be a performance issue with the joins.
If this is the case, then using ElasticSearch to index your models will eliminate that.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/307-elasticsearch-part-2
There are of course other full text search engines out there, Solr, Sphinx

Comment: Thanks.  Think I missed the Squeel-cast!